# Count different actions within one hour in python

Tags: pandas, time-series, counting

I am starting to work with time series. I have one of a user doing bank transfers to different countries, however the most frequent country to where he/she is doing the transfers is X, but there are transfers also to the countries Y and Z. Let's say:

```
date                           id       country
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z       id_01     X
2020-01-01T00:20:00.000Z       id_02     X
2020-01-01T00:25:00.000Z       id_03     Y
2020-01-01T00:35:00.000Z       id_04     X
2020-01-01T00:45:00.000Z       id_05     Z
2020-01-01T01:00:00.000Z       id_06     X
2020-01-01T10:20:00.000Z       id_07     X
2020-01-01T10:25:00.000Z       id_08     X
2020-01-01T13:00:00.000Z       id_09     X
2020-01-01T18:45:00.000Z       id_10     Z
2020-01-01T18:55:00.000Z       id_11     X
```

Since the most frequent country is X, I would like to count iteratively how many transactions have been done within one hour (in the whole list of events) to countries different than X.

The format of the expected output for this particular case would be:

```
date                           id        country
2020-01-01T00:25:00.000Z       id_03     Y
2020-01-01T00:45:00.000Z       id_05     Z
```

Starting from `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, within one hour there are two Y, Z transactions. Then starting from `2020-01-01T00:20:00.000Z`, within one hour, there are the same transactions, and so on. Then, starting from `2020-01-01T10:20:00.000Z`, within one hour, all are X. Starting from `2020-01-01T18:45:00.000Z`, within one hour, there is only one Z.

I am trying with a double for loop and .value_counts(), but I'm not sure of what I am doing.

Comment: dear @Ben.T I reshaped the question and added a new event.

Comment: the expected output looks more like you want to select only the rows with country not X so something like `df[df['country'].ne('X')]`. I don't see any count in it?

Comment: No because in the output id_10 is not included

Comment: so it is because id_10 is the only non X within 1 hour before and after, it is not selected? if I rephrase you want the rows, not X, only if there is at least another row non X within 1 hour? sorry I just try to figure out where the count thing comes in

Comment: @Ben.T indeed, since within one hour there is only one Z, then id_10 is out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can select only the rows not X, then use `diff` once forward and once backward (within 1 hour before and after) and you want where any of the two diff is below a `Timedelta` of 1h.

```
#convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#mask not X and select only these rows
mX = df['country'].ne('X')
df_ = df[mX].copy()

# mask within an hour before and after 
m1H = (df_['date'].diff().le(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) | 
        df_['date'].diff(-1).le(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) )

# selet only the rows meeting criteria on X and 1H
df_ = df_[m1H]
print (df_)
                       date     id country
2 2020-01-01 00:25:00+00:00  id_03       Y
4 2020-01-01 00:45:00+00:00  id_05       Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a time-series database for this? It could make your life easier if you are doing a lot of event-based aggregations with arbitrary time intervals. Time-series databases abstract this for you so all you need is to send a query and get the results into pandas. It's also going to run considerably faster.

For example hourly aggregations can be done using the following syntax in QuestDB.

```
select timestamp, country, count() from yourTable SAMPLE BY 1h
```

this will return results like this

```
| timestamp           | country | count |
| 2020-06-22T00:00:00 | X       | 234   |
| 2020-06-22T00:00:00 | Y       | 493   |
| 2020-06-22T01:00:00 | X       |  12   |
| 2020-06-22T01:00:00 | Y       |  66   |
```

You can adjust this to monthly or weekly or 5-minute resolution results without having to re-write your logic, all you need to do is change the `1h` to `1M`,`7d` or `5m` or pass this as an argument.

Now, to get results one hour before and after the timestamp of your target transaction, you could add a timestamp interval search to the above. For example assuming your target transaction happened on `2010-01-01T06:47:00.000000Z`, the resulting search would be

```
select hour, country, count() from yourTable 
where timestamp = '2010-01-01T05:47:00.000000Z;2h' 
sample by 1h;
```

If this is something which would work for you, there is a tutorial on how to run this type of query in QuestDB and get the results into pandas [here](https://dev.to/davidgs/questdb-with-python-291j)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
(df.country != 'X').groupby(by=df.date.dt.hour).sum()
```

First it turns your date columns into a datetime. Then, you test if country is 'X', and group by hour, and sum the number of countries that are different than 'X'. Groups are based on hours, and not on rolling elasped time. Hope it solves your problem!