# Remove similar records with times within one hour of each other

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, duplicates, timedelta

I have an Excel file containing calls with various timestamps and other data. Example below:

```
ID   Date        Time        Call Number     Report Number        Location
00   2020-12-01  15:47:00    12345           104                  123 Main St
01   2020-12-01  16:13:00    13344                                123 Main St #1
02   2020-12-01  15:29:00    15555           201                  12 President St
03   2020-12-01  17:41:00    17342           304                  12 President St
04   2020-12-02  07:04:00    19001           402                  123 Main St
```

I am assuming that calls within one hour of each other and having the same/similar location are duplicates of each other. I want to find these "duplicates" and only keep the record that has the most information - in this example, ID 01 should be removed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475540/count-different-actions-within-one-hour-in-python) was very helpful in finding the records within one hour of each other. After combining the Date and Time columns into "tstamp", the code below works well to identify those timestamps within one hour of each other:

```
mask1hour = (df['tstamp'].diff().le(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) | df['tstamp'].diff(-1).le(pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) )
```

My thoughts are to use a groupby Location on the dataframe, but that wouldn't handle small differences (typos, extra information) between locations. I'm also unsure on how to go about keeping the record with more complete data. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: give different ids to each unique mask1hour, than implement pandas .drop_duplicates() using your required columns in subset param: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Thanks Artyom! The problem here is keep is only restricted to "first" or "last" - and there's no pattern for which record will have more information. Also, I'm not sure how to handle slight differences in the Location column when using that as a subset.

Comment: does longer location imply more complete? To deal with typos you will need to write your typo checker or use some algorithm (ML, or something simple) to compare whether information is similar or not. I am not sure that there is an "out of the box" solution

Comment: Gotcha. No, longer location does not imply more complete - I'm just looking at other empty vs. filled columns (like Report Number).

Comment: The definition of "small differences  (typos, extra information)" is vague. Would computing the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between two locations and comparing it to a threshold work for you? The threshold can either be something like "if edit distance < 5 then locations are similar" or "if edit distance is less than 5% of the length of the longest string then locations are similar"